# Displaying specific images in bootstrap carousel

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Like the title said, I want to display a specific type of images. I have a Model named Skills and inside it, there is a type object where users can choose between "Certification" and "Others". Right now, the carousel is working, but it is displaying both "Certification" and "Others" but I only want it to display "Certifications" images. One thing to note is that I have both the "Certification" and "Others" images in the same page but for "Others", I don't need it to be in a carousel.

I'm thinking I might have to create another Model specifically for "Certification" but I am wondering if there is an alternative. Any help is appreciated, thank you. I added an image below to show you how it looks like right now.

[Picture of how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KokC.png)

```
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel  slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-indicators">
         <!--Index will automatically give a numeric value-->
         @foreach (var img in Model.Skill.Select
         ((image, index) => new { Image = image, Index = index }))
         {
             <!--The class="(imageWithIndex.Index == 0 ? "active" : "")" lets 0 active-->
             <button hidden type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="@img.Index"
                     class="@(img.Index==0?"active":"")" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
         }

     </div>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
         @foreach (var img in Model.Skill.Select
         ((image, index) => new { Image = image, Index = index }))
         {
             <div class="@(img.Index==0?"carousel-item active":"carousel-item")">
                 <div class="p-1 m-2 text-center">
                     <!--Display the image-->
                     <img src="@img.Image.ImageUrl" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                 </div>
             </div>
       
         }
     </div>
     <!--The previous and next button-->
     <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
     </button>
     <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
     </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use Comic Sans MS font for a professional anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative. I basically copied and pasted everything from w3schools and changed the code a little. The thing I changed was the HTML section. The CSS/Javascript was kept as is.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
<!--Display the images-->
    @foreach(var img in Model.Skill)
    {
        @if(img.type == "Certification")
        {
            <div class="mySlides faade">
                <img src="@img.ImageUrl" style="width:100%" />
            </div>
        }
    }

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<!--For The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
    @foreach (var img in Model.Skill)
    {
        @if (img.type == "Certification")
        {
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(@img.Id)"></span>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try below code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel  slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        @foreach (var img in Model.Skill.Select((image, index) => new { Image = image, Index = index }))
        {
            if (img.Image.SkillType == "Certification") 
            {
                <button hidden type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="@img.Index"
                        class="@(img.Index==0?"active":"")" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach (var img in Model.Skill.Select((image, index) => new { Image = image, Index = index }))
        {
            if (img.Image.SkillType == "Certification") 
            {
                <div class="@(img.Index==0?"carousel-item active":"carousel-item")">
                    <div class="p-1 m-2 text-center">
                        <img src="@img.Image.ImageUrl" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <!-- The previous and next buttons remain the same -->
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: When I use the "if (img.Image.SkillType == "Certification")", the images are not displaying anymore. It does look like it should work since I did a similar thing for "Others". EX:             @foreach (var obj in Model.Skill)
            {
                @if(obj.type == "Other")
                {
                    <img src="@obj.ImageUrl" class="otherLogo" />
                }
            }